# List All the transactions of an adress - API

Tags: transactions, address, api

I am looking for a way to list all the transactions of an address. For instance, if we use the Blokchain.info API we get:

```
url='https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1PFtrRjbq4aLfM7k4tyLZ3ZAuTsgLr6Q8Q'
request=requests.get(url)
addr=request.json()
```

Total number of transactions that have ever been made:

```
addr['n_tx']
69990
```

Now if we want to access to the list of these transactions:

```
addr['txs']
```

We get a list of transactions that have been by this address, but when we check the lenght of this list to see how much transactions we got:

```
len(addr['txs'])
```

we find 50.

With Blockexplorer API, we can have up to 1000 transactions for an adress.
I have tried some other API like SoChain, still the same issue (only 50 transactions).

**Do you know a way to have access to all the transactions given an adress** - just the list of their hashes - (in our case it is 69990) ?

I do not want to download the blockchain because I just do not have enough space for it.

Thank you !

Comment: All of these APIs allow paginations, so you can get 1 page of 50, then another of 51-100, then 101-150 and so on.

Comment: The issue is that the API call rate limit is very strict, so in order to build the list of transactions since the genesis block will take a lot of time..

Comment: Yes, but you only need to do it once. Spend a day or so pulling in all that data, then save it locally. Once you have that, you just need to check from the last block you have locally. Also, I don't think they are that strict. 70k txs should be easily retrievable in a few hours.